# Closest power to another power

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am interested in finding the closest power of one number to another. Specifically, if we have $k,m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$, and $m<n$, how can we minimize $n^k-m^{\lfloor\log_m(n^k)\rfloor}$? Heuristically, as k increases so does the difference, but I cannot seem to demonstrate this conclusively.

Comment: Presumably $m,n$ are given, and $k$ is free, right?

Comment: It is not important that $\gcd (m,n)=1$.  Generally the differences will increase because powers are scarce, but there are accidents like $2^{10}\approx 10^3$ where the difference is only $24$ while $2^9$ is $412$ away from any power of $10$

Comment: We may ask whether for some $m,n$  and for some $r\in \Bbb N,$ there are infinitely many $k$ such that $ m^{a_k+1}>n^k=r+m^{a_k}$  (where $a_k\in \Bbb N)$. This will depend on "how well" we can approximate $(\ln n)/\ln m$ from below by rationals...